# classList array wont print output to the user

Tags: c++, arrays, class, visual-studio-2013

So the point of this program is to ask the student for their first name, how many classes they're taking this semester, and then it asks for the names of each of those classes. My problem is that I can't get the `classList` array to work and display the class names back to the user in the program output. I've marked where I think the issue is coming from and I think its a super easy fix but I'm just not seeing it. Help?

I'm coding this in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public: //public class for the student 
    Student(string first_name, string last_name, int num, string list);
    Student();


    void input(); //input from the user
    void output(); //output for the user depending on their input


    // accessors 
    const string get_name();
    const int get_numClasses();
    const string get_classList();


    // mutators
    void set_name(string name);
    void set_numClasses(int num);
    void set_classList(string list);


private: 
    string name;
    int numClasses;
    string classList;
};


// constructor's variable
Student::Student() 
{
    name;
    numClasses = 0;
    classList;
}


// the accessors get called from the public class Student
string const Student::get_name()
{
    return name;
}
int const Student::get_numClasses()
{
    return numClasses;
}
string const Student::get_classList()
{
    return classList;
}


// the mutators set for the public class Student
void Student::set_name(string studentName)
{
    name = studentName;
}
void Student::set_numClasses(int num)
{
    numClasses = num;
}
void Student::set_classList(string list)
{
    classList = list;
}


// accessors here
void Student::input()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Enter your name (First name only): ";
    cin >> name;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "How many classes are you taking this semester?: ";
    cin >> numClasses;
    cin.ignore();

    if (numClasses> 0)
    {
        string* classList = new std::string[numClasses]; // <--- THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE I THINK
        for (x = 0; x<numClasses; x++) // loop for the classList array
        {
            cout << "Enter name of class " << (x + 1) << endl;
            cin >> classList[x]; // <--- OR MAYBE THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE TOO?
        }
    }

    cout << '\n' << endl;
}


// displays the output according to the user
void Student::output()
{
    cout << "Students name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Number of classes this semester?: " << numClasses << endl;
    cout << "Displayed Class List: " << classList << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char go_again = 'Y';
    while (go_again == 'y' || go_again == 'Y')
    {
        Student s1;
        s1.input();

        s1.output(); //output from the student

        cout << "\nRestart with new data? (press y/n) " << endl;
        cin >> go_again;
    }


    if (go_again == 'n')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Lines like `name;` do nothing. I suspect that you expect it to initialize your variable, but you need an *initialization list* for that. (Look it up in your book.)

Answer (score 3):

Your `Student` class declares a `string` named `classList`, but your `input()` method declares a new variable of type `string*`, also named `classList`.  It's called shadowing, and, while legal, is to be avoided, for exactly the kind of problems your are seeing.  It is usually unintended and nearly always confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class member named `classList` of type `std::string`.

However, you also declare a different `classList` in the `input` function: `string* classList = new std::string[numClasses];`

This does not modify the `classList` class data member. It is a local variable which shadows the class data member.

You can just append each class name to the class data member and avoid the array.

```
// string* classList = new std::string[numClasses];
std::string className;

for (x = 0; x<numClasses; x++) // loop for the classList array
{
    cout << "Enter name of class " << (x + 1) << endl;
    //cin >> classList[x];
    cin >> className;

    classList += className + " ";
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I'm still learning what I can but I love that whenever I get stuck and reading+youtube tutorials aren't helping I can post here and nice people will help me! Thank you!!